# Is there any way to pass http headers when I use desktop.browse method in java?

Tags: java, browser, http-headers

I want to use `browse()` method from `java.awt.Desktop` class to open a web page, but the problem that I need to set some http headers for a specific values like Cookies.

How could I do that? if Desktop.browse() not suitable, Is there any other solution that allows me to open a browser window with the mentioned status above?

Answer (score 1):

`Desktop.browse(...)` just lauches your default browser with the URL you give it. You cannot influence what the browser sends to request that URI, as it is up to the browser. If you know which browser will be opened you might manipulate its session storage on disk before launching it, but I would not recommend this. If this is all about a session-cookie, you might be able to give the session cookie as URL parameter instead, but that depends on the Webserver you are querying and you have to try whether this would work.

Other than that, you could download the URL yourself in the Java code, setting any headers you like, store the result to a temporary file and then open that file as URI via `Desktop.browse(...)`.